# Git diff with remote tag

Tags: git, tags, diff

I'm about to merge a big change from a remote branch (non-origin), and more specifically from a given tag.

There are two remotes then:

1. `origin`
2. `proposal`

On the `proposal` remote, a branch name `idea` exists, with a tag `tagged_idea`.

The idea is that I want to review the incoming changes between `tagged_idea` and my current HEAD. How can I achieve this?

I tried something like `git diff .../proposal/tags/tagged_idea` but it didn't work well. Any idea?

In other terms, what I would like to see is the result of the merge, before even doing it in my branch. Just like if I did the pull `git pull proposal tags/tagged_idea` but without actually making the changes.

Comment: where do you want to see the changes if nothing must be changed? at least my workflow usually allows to do all kind of merging/changing/... in my local copy, which is easy enough to undo if i don't like it. once i do like it, it get's pushed to the proper remote.

Comment: I'd love something equivalent to the output of a diff.

Comment: so what do you mean by "it didn't work well"?

Comment: roughly equivalent to "didn't work at all". Basically git didn't accept the command.

Comment: try `git diff tagged_idea` then

Comment: Pretty sure I tried it, and it didn't work. Now it does, as I pulled the changes, but before I didn't have the tag in my local repository, therefore the tag could not be found by git (hence the `proposal/...`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most git commands only work locally, esp. things like `git diff` and `git merge`.

Your local repository can have multiple remotes, but in order to work on these, you must first sync the local repository with your remotes:

```
 git fetch --all
```

While this will download all the changesets, it will not apply them to your current branch, unless the current branch is *tracking* one of the remotes.

Once you have downloaded the remote changesets and tags, you can simply run something like:

```
git diff tagged_idea
```

... and see the diff between your current `HEAD` and a tag `tagged_idea`, wherever the latter resides.

Comment: If you use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, you'll still get all the new commits, but git will not attempt to merge (or rebase, depending on `pull.rebase` and other git config settings) any of those changes even if you're on a "tracking" branch.  (There's a minor caveat if you normally track a force-pushed remote branch and auto-rebase with the "smart" rebase that `git pull --rebase` can do, but that's a *very* unusual work-flow.)

Comment: This does not work when you have local and remote tags with the same name. It only compares against the local tag.

Answer (score 3):

I use `git ls-remote --tags proposal |grep tagged_idea` to get the revision hash, then do `git diff` with the hash.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me (the tags on the remote weren't fetched because the names matched the tags locally).  Of course, the whole purpose of the diff was to see *if* there were any differences and where they came from: catch 22 ;)

Comment: The hash definitively identifies the tag. Use `git show-ref --tags -d` to view local and remote tags. The local name should be followed by `^{}` if there is a collision with an identically named tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not use it, if you are only looking for a command because the main intention of this solution is to introduce you a way of solutions !**

To make life easier - i wrote a script [git-cheat-sheet](https://github.com/tomonir/git-cheat-sheet) ,that contains some useful commands , including the following:

./git_commands.sh -diff_tag